# why is there a 13 mm limit on hand drilling?

Tags: drill

Why are hand drilling tools (corder, cordless, pneumatic etc) limited to 13 mm (1/2 inch) in metal, but not in concrete or wood?

Comment: I guess it depends on the drill and type of bit used. I drill much deeper than this regularly.

Comment: Haven't heard that rule -- where did you find it? (I presume that's diameter, not depth...)

Comment: This is the same thing as fractional chucks being mostly 1/2" capacity, which is just that, the chuck capacity. If you are using a hole saw you can go much bigger than 1/2" or 13mm. Depends on the power of the drill.

Comment: Right. Or many other kinds of bit which also have a narrow shaft for the chuck to grip even though the working end of the bit is wider. So the "limit" appears to be a misunderstanding...?

Comment: Google "blacksmith drill" for metal bits that are bigger than 13mm but fit a 13mm chuck. I have several up to 25mm and also a "step drill" for sheet material.

Comment: If we are talking diameter I drill up to 2" in mild steel (I beams) with a carbide tip hole saw set.